# What is the correct syntax for flock with bash options in cron

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flock

I have the following cron job

```
7,22,37,52 6-16 * * * myuser    /bin/bash -l -c "cd /to/my/path/; rake my_rake_task"
```

I need to use this with some file locking so the task doesn't run more than once, and looking about, I see flock is a good tool for this scenario.

My question is, what is the right syntax for using flock with the above?  Here's what I'm guessing, but, I have the extra user definition and so forth.

Is this correct?

```
flock -n /var/run/my_app.lock -c 7,22,37,52 6-16 * * * myuser    /bin/bash -l -c "cd /to/my/path/; execute_my_command"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is *not* correct. See `man crontab` for syntax of the crontab files. The correct command would look like:

```
7,22,37,52 6-16 * * *  myuser  /bin/bash -l -c "cd /to/my/path/ && flock -n /var/run/my_app.lock -c execute_my_command"
```

..but a cleaner approach is to put it into a wrapper script and run that script from `cron`.

Comment: Ah, I see - so it literally goes with the command, not the entire cron command.  Also I see what you mean by having it in a wrapper script, though I noticed using single quotes helps flock know how to `'execute a command'` and overcomes "flock: -c requires exactly one command argument" - Thanks Alexander